# android market is not showing my published application

Tags: android

i have published android app but not appearing in android market.i m using android 2.2 and i have tried in samsung galaxy that is not showing my application so just give me some idea to fix this problem.

this is my manifest.xml file:

```
    <activity android:name=".Full"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
           android:label="@string/app_name">
           <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Short"
           android:label="@string/app_name">
           <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 

   </application>
```

Please help me..

Comment: i dont understand ur que. have you a android market publisher a/c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android market appears to be experiencing some problems for many isers currently. Many people are unable to download anything from it. I would imagine that your problem is related to this. And i would guess it will be fixed tomorrow if not in a few hours or less.

Comment: See here: http://www.engadget.com/2011/02/01/android-market-acting-weird-is-it-a-precursor-to-tomorrows-e/

Answer (score 1):

Check your developer console for the market. Make sure that you see your app in the console and that it say "published" on the right. If that's all there, click on the app name to see the details and then expand the section on market filtering. It might explain there why your app may not be showing up on your galaxy tab.

Or, like @Tim says, you may just need to be patient. The market infrastructure for developers still has quite a few warts.